# OAuth2orize login flow looping infinitely

Tags: node.js, oauth, oauth2orize

Looking to get an OAuth2 endpoint set up for my website. I am using OAuth2orize on the OAuth server, and passport-oauth on the client server.

I'm using [the oauth2orize example](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize/blob/master/examples/express2/oauth2.js) almost verbatim to get it working first.

When I begin the login flow, it sends me to the login page (good so far), I log in and it sends me to the dialog (also good), and then when I click allow, it just loops me back to the same page over and over again (the allow/deny dialog).

Anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong? I know it's actually sending me back to my app (with code, that my app **should** exchange for a token), but it seems to just bounce me right back to the dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out passport-oauth2 does not play nice with peerjs-server:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2/issues/19